# OrderedEnumerableRowCollection to Type System.IConvertible

Tags: c#, linq

I get the Exception in the Following code, how can i resolve it?

```
DataTable RDT = new DataTable();
RDT = ds.Tables[0];
List<int> result = new List<int>();
Random rand = new Random();
result.Add(Convert.ToInt32(RDT.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => rand.Next())));
```

Exception on the last line:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.OrderedEnumerableRowCollection`1[System.Data.DataRow]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Comment: Seems an appropriate error. You are trying to `Convert.ToInt32` something that cannot be converted because it's something entirely different. Only **you** can fix this, we don't know what you **want**. We only know what you failed at.

Comment: There is only one column in datatable that has integer values and i want to pick the integer values randomly and save it in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataTable RDT = new DataTable();
RDT = ds.Tables[0];
Random rand = new Random();
List<int> result = RDT.AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(row => Convert.ToInt32(row[0]))
                      .OrderBy(r => rand.Next())
                      .ToList();
```

You need to convert the first field from each row, instead or the complete collection of rows.

Don't forget `using System.Linq`